# Assign an ID of a dynamically created link to a global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dynamic, delegation

I have the following code structure:
index.html - linked to script.js
description.html linked to both script.js and description.js

The code from the index.html:

```html
<div id="restaurants">
  <div id="restaurants-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

In the div#restaurants-wrapper I would like to insert, dynamically, after fetching data using the foursquare Places API the following code from the script.js file:

```js
document.getElementById('restaurants-wrapper').innerHTML +=
'<div class="restaurant"><div class="restaurant-img">' + '<img src="' + 
picture + '" alt="restaurant image">' + '</div><div class="restaurant-desc">
<div class="restaurant-name"><a id="' + name.toLowerCase() + '" 
class="restaurant-name-link" href=../html/description.html>' + name + '</a>
</div><div class="restaurant-dist">' + distance + ' km</div></div></div>'
```

```html
<div id="restaurants">
<div id="restaurants-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Now, these links need to go to the same page, called description.html, for example, that will, again, dynamically render the data from the global variables in the first .js document (script.js linked to index.html).

When I tried this:

```
$('#restaurants-list').on('click', 'a', function () {
restaurantName = $(this).attr('id')
console.log(window.restaurantName)
})
```

The global variable is still undefined, when trying to access it via the second .js file, that will render the description.html page. Additionally, console.log(window.restaurantName) doesn't log anything, the link loads the description page instantly. Also, calling console.log(window.restaurantName) in the second .js file, the restaurantName is undefined.

What seems to be the issue here?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like your `click` event listener is not working at all. Console log something there

Comment: `console.log(window.restaurantName)` => `console.log(restaurantName)`

Comment: It throws an alert() for example

Comment: console.log(restaurantName) => same issue

Comment: console.log($(this).attr('id')) => nothing in the console;

Comment: alert($(this).attr('id')) => gives and ID
restaurantName = $(this).attr('id') and then calling it from another .js file (linked to the same .html file) => undefined

Comment: `href=../html/description.html` you are missing the quotes around the attribute value

Comment: Maulen, here yes, it's not a typo in my code, just here, first time asking, got confused with the formating...